# Barcode scanners with intent capabilities

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application I'm giving users ability to scan bar code.
Now I'm pushing users to install **ZXing**'s scanner.

Are there other bar code scanners which can handle intents (supporting *startActivityForResult*)?

Comment: why don't you try with embedding zxing barcode scanner within your app instead of pushing users to install it on their devices?

Comment: @kjurkovic it was released in 2011. Now I'm asking same question to myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [open source project](https://code.google.com/p/android-quick-response-code/). It is created using Zxing lib, but it is light weight and quick for scanning QR codes. Hope you will find it useful.

And also, [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-zxinglib/) library is the best and easy if you only need to scan QR codes.

Answer (score 1):

[ZBar barcode reader](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html) is simple easy and handy to use this is in support with `startActivityForResult`

Answer (score 1):

If the Barcode Scanner is installed on your Android device, you can have it scan for you and return the result, just by sending it an Intent. For example, you can hook up a button to scan a QR code like this:

```
public Button.OnClickListener mScan = new Button.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
};
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
if (requestCode == 0) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        // Handle successful scan
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // Handle cancel
    }
 }
 }
```

Also change your manifest file according to below code:

> ```
>     <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
>        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
>        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
>        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
>        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
>  <intent-filter>
>   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
>   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
>  </intent-filter>
>  <intent-filter>
>      <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
>        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
>      </intent-filter>
>      </activity>
> ```

For more options, like scanning a product barcode, or asking Barcode Scanner to encode and display a barcode for you, see [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java):

And [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/androidtest/src/com/google/zxing/client/androidtest/ZXingTestActivity.java) some source from our test app which shows how to use them: